# How to exit the application which consists of few classes?

Tags: android, libgdx

My first class "public class MyActivity extends Activity"
immediately runs another class "public class MyActivity2 extends AndroidApplication",

which runs Libgdx "class MyGame".

I exit MyGame class with "Gdx.app.exit()", which returns to first class.
But it starts second class again... Cycle.
So how to exit the application?
Thanks!

Comment: Then why do you need MainActivity? why not start with MyActivity2?

Comment: Before starting Activity2 you can finish the Activity1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an exit button/menuitem in other activities, and when that button is pressed start the MainActivity and pass in an intent extra.

Goes something like this:
In other acitivities:

```
private void exit() {
      Intent intentHome = new Intent(this, Main.class);
      intentHome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      intentHome.putExtra("EXIT", true);
      startActivity(intentHome); finish();
}
```

In Main/First Activity:

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
         finish();
}
```

Also you could finish() each activity when starting the next one, to make sure no other activity is in the background.

Comment: Thank you. But as for second your thought. How can I finish the first activity? If I add "finish()" before starting second activity, the first will finish on startup. I have no menus in first activity. It just starts the second, because I can't use Display properties in  "AndroidApplication". So I use such trick with the first activity, which is "Activity". I have simple idea thought. I can use boolean variable, which is on exit purpose. So after return to first activity it will check this value and finish.

Comment: Strange. My idea does not. Black screen after return to first activity. I added the following to the first activity:         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Data.exit) finish(); I do "Data.exit=true" in other class before return to first activity.

Comment: I tried this code in first activity: startActivity(myIntent);
            finish(); But I got black screen and hang when I try to exit my third class (libgdx class).

Comment: You don't have to finish the first activity, just when starting intents from other activities. And when you want to exit from any other activity just call the exit() method. And in the Main activity insert the if statement before any code before setContentView() in onCreate or in onResume.

Comment: Hmm. Your exit() will not work in my  AndroidApplication activity because startActivity is not allowed there. But I found my mistake with boolean Data.exit value. I checked it in first activity. I added "if (Data.exit)" to my second activity. And yes, it found when third activity finished. And the app exits normally. It was the easiest solution. Thank you for advices!